# How to count each x entries and mark the occurence of this sequence with a value in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to create a column C (based on B) which counts each beginning of a series of 4 entries in B (or the dataframe as general). I have the following pandas data frame:

```
A B 
1 100
2 102
3 103
4 104
5 105
6 106
7 108
8 109
9 110
10 112
11 113
12 115
13 116
14 118
15 120
16 121
```

I want to create the following column C:

```
A C
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 2
6 2
7 2
8 2
9 3
10 3
11 3
12 3
13 4
14 4
15 4
16 4
```

This column C should count each series of 4 entries of the dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution is create numpy array by `np.arange`, then use integer division by `4` and add `1`, because python count from `0`:

```
df['C'] = np.arange(len(df)) // 4 + 1
print (df)
     A    B  C
0    1  100  1
1    2  102  1
2    3  103  1
3    4  104  1
4    5  105  2
5    6  106  2
6    7  108  2
7    8  109  2
8    9  110  3
9   10  112  3
10  11  113  3
11  12  115  3
12  13  116  4
13  14  118  4
14  15  120  4
15  16  121  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['C'] = df.index // 4 + 1
```

Given that you have fairly simple dataframe it's okay to assume that you have generic index which is a [RangeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html) object.

In your example it would look like this:

```
df.index
#RangeIndex(start=0, stop=16, step=1)
```

That being said values of this index are the following:

```
df.index.values
#array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], dtype=int64)
```

Converting such array into your desired output is performed using the formula:

```
x // 4 + 1
```

Where `//` is the operator used for [floor division](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html).

Comment: please add some explantion, when solution working - rangeIndex and some description...